# Inexplicable vertical border behavior in a simple table

Tags: tables, border

The code below prints the picture below, and I cannot figure out why the vertical borders act like they do. Obviously, I would like the line to go from the toprule to the bottomrule, but for some reason one line goes past the bottomrule while two of them don't start until row number two.

Can anyone help me modify the code to make it look alright? I am in a bit of a rush.

Thank you very much.

[image]

```
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Results from running the main model for different scenarios}
\begin{tabular}{l|ccc|c|ccc|ccc} 
\toprule 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Weights}}
  & \textbf{Obj.}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Weighted pen.}} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Total pen.}} \\
\textbf{Variation}           & 1   & 2   & 3  & \textbf{value}  & 1 & 2 & 3  & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\cmidrule(r){1-11} 
Even weights          & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 55.67  & 26.67 & 4.33   & 24.67 & 80    & 13    & 74\\
Emphasised 1          & 1/2   & 1/4   & 1/4   & 60.75 & 36   & 4.25  & 20.5 & 72    & 17    & 82\\
Emphasised 2          & 1/4   & 1/2   & 1/4   & 44.5  & 21   & 4.5   & 19   & 84    & 9     & 76\\
Emphasised 3          & 1/4   & 1/4   & 1/2   & 60.25 & 20   & 8.25  & 32   & 80    & 33    & 64\\
No lunch              & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 43    & 21   & 2.67  & 19.33& 63    & 8     & 58 \\
No R\&D on lab 4      & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 27    & 1.33 & 3.67  & 22   & 4     & 11    & 66 \\
New lab of type 3     & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 49    & 24   & 5     & 20   & 72    & 15    & 60 \\
\bottomrule
\label{tab:scenariotable}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You are missing `|` in the argument to `\multicolumn`; the `\label` command is misplaced, it should go next to `\caption` *outside* `tabular`

Comment: Egreg, I love you!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `|` specifiers in the argument to `\multicolumn`. Also `\label` is misplaced: it should go just after `\caption`.

I recommend you not trying to place big tables with `center` and `\captionof`: leave them float.

Here's a fixed code, with another version, without vertical rules and with `siunitx` for better alignment of the numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Results from running the main model for different scenarios}\label{tab:scenariotable}

\begin{tabular}{l|ccc|c|ccc|ccc} 
\toprule 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Weights}}
  & \textbf{Obj.}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Weighted pen.}} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Total pen.}} \\
\textbf{Variation}           & 1   & 2   & 3  & \textbf{value}  & 1 & 2 & 3  & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\cmidrule(r){1-11} 
Even weights          & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 55.67  & 26.67 & 4.33   & 24.67 & 80    & 13    & 74\\
Emphasised 1          & 1/2   & 1/4   & 1/4   & 60.75 & 36   & 4.25  & 20.5 & 72    & 17    & 82\\
Emphasised 2          & 1/4   & 1/2   & 1/4   & 44.5  & 21   & 4.5   & 19   & 84    & 9     & 76\\
Emphasised 3          & 1/4   & 1/4   & 1/2   & 60.25 & 20   & 8.25  & 32   & 80    & 33    & 64\\
No lunch              & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 43    & 21   & 2.67  & 19.33& 63    & 8     & 58 \\
No R\&D on lab 4      & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 27    & 1.33 & 3.67  & 22   & 4     & 11    & 66 \\
New lab of type 3     & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 49    & 24   & 5     & 20   & 72    & 15    & 60 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Results from running the main model for different scenarios}\label{tab:scenariotablebetter}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  ccc
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule 
\textbf{Variation}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Weights}}
  & \textbf{Obj.}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Weighted pen.}} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Total pen.}} \\
  & {1} & {2} & {3} & {\textbf{value}}  & {1} & {2} & {3}  & {1} & {2} & {3} \\
\midrule 
Even weights       & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 55.67 & 26.67 & 4.33 & 24.67 & 80 & 13 & 74 \\
Emphasised 1       & 1/2 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 60.75 & 36    & 4.25 & 20.5  & 72 & 17 & 82 \\
Emphasised 2       & 1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4 & 44.5  & 21    & 4.5  & 19    & 84 &  9 & 76 \\
Emphasised 3       & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 & 60.25 & 20    & 8.25 & 32    & 80 & 33 & 64 \\
No lunch           & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 43    & 2 1   & 2.67 & 19.33 & 63 &  8 & 58 \\
No R\&D on lab 4   & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 27    &  1.33 & 3.67 & 22    &  4 & 11 & 66 \\
New lab of type 3  & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 49    & 24    & 5    & 20    & 72 & 15 & 60 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The tabular environment is wider than the text block, unless that width has been increased somehow.

Comment: @Mico I didn't address that aspect, as I don't know the final format.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than figure out how to insert the "missing" vertical bars, you may want to think about structuring your table so that it has a more open look, a better-organized header and better-organized numeric data, *and* actually fits inside the available textblock. In the code below, I employ the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package for 7 of the data columns, and a `tabular*` environment so that the table occupies the full width of the available text block, but no more than that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,siunitx}
% Utility macro to typeset single-column wrapped header cells:
\newcommand\mycol[1]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Results from running the main model for different scenarios} 
\label{tab:scenariotable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out optimal amount of intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
                  l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                  *{3}{c}  
                  *{4}{S[table-format=2.2]}
                  *{3}{S[table-format=3.0]} } 
\toprule 
  Variation
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Weights}
  & {\mycol{Obj.\\value}}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Weighted pen.} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Total pen.} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{9-11}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & & {1} & {2} & {3} & {1} & {2} & {3}\\
\midrule 
Even weights          & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 55.67  & 26.67 & 4.33   & 24.67 & 80    & 13    & 74\\
Emphasised 1          & 1/2   & 1/4   & 1/4   & 60.75 & 36   & 4.25  & 20.5 & 72    & 17    & 82\\
Emphasised 2          & 1/4   & 1/2   & 1/4   & 44.5  & 21   & 4.5   & 19   & 84    & 9     & 76\\
Emphasised 3          & 1/4   & 1/4   & 1/2   & 60.25 & 20   & 8.25  & 32   & 80    & 33    & 64\\
No lunch              & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 43    & 21   & 2.67  & 19.33& 63    & 8     & 58 \\
No R\&D on lab 4      & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 27    & 1.33 & 3.67  & 22   & 4     & 11    & 66 \\
New lab of type 3     & 1/3   & 1/3   & 1/3   & 49    & 24   & 5     & 20   & 72    & 15    & 60 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow that looks a lot better. Where would I specify a right-justification of all the numerical values in the table?

Comment: @jnrk - for simple right-alignment, use the `r` column type.

Comment: Where should this be specified?

Comment: @jnrk - In the second argument of the `tabular*` environment. E.g., if you wanted the contents of all ten data columns to be right-aligned (instead of either centered or aligned on the decimal marker), you'd write `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{10}{r}}`.